# Help with joining a large DBF file to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins, animation, time

My overall objective is to create a time line animation depicting when a person is working in a particular region.  The .dbf table consists of over 6000 record entries of shift data, including date start and date stop times along with an assignment ID.  I have approximately 100 different shapes/regions also with assignment ID's.  I would like for that region to turn on or off based of the table shift data and show when someone is working that region.

When I join the table to the shapefile, only the first shift entry gets attached and displayed.  Do I have to have 6000 shapes for each of the 6000 record entries?

There has to be a better way, please help.

Comment: can we get some small screenshots or data samples?

Comment: try http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15260 Join - (shapefile to shapefile / dbf to shapefile)

Comment: Do you have the Tracking Analyst extension for ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to do a many-to-one relationship join.

Comment: I'm not certain that processing for relationships is fully functional in ArcGIS 10 without an ArcInfo license. If this is the case, you may need to reconsider your methodology moving forward.

Comment: Creating related tables (an ArcMap function) is available to ArcView and above licenses.  Creating Relationship Classes (a geodatabase function) is available to ArcEditor & ArcInfo license.  This help page details the differences- http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/

Comment: When I join the poly shape file to the table only the first shift entry from the table attaches, one for each shape.  I can join the table to the shape file and the attribute table comes out the way it should, all 6000 shifts connected to each shape based off of the assign ID field, but how do I get a table to display a shape?  Hope that makes since!  Tried attaching a screen shot, but not sure how on this website.  Thank you all for your help/input!